# Haskell Function Composition and Partial Aplication

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am currently learning **Haskell** and I have some trouble to understand **function composition mixted with partial aplication**. For example:

I had to make my own version of the function *nub* from the *Data.List* library, the function deletes the repeated elements of a list respecting the position of the first appereance. Example:

`nub [1,3,1,2,7,2,9] -> [1,3,2,7,9]`

My version is:

```
nub' :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] 
nub' = foldr (\x ys -> x : (filter (/=x) ys)) []
```

Because the function will be infix (because of foldr) the first value my lambda functions gets is the head of the list and the second is the solution of the recursive call. My procese to "simplify" it was the next:

```
(\x ys -> x : (filter (/=x) ys))

(\x ys -> (:) x (filter (/=x) ys)) = (\x ys -> (x :) (filter (/=x) ys))

(\x -> (x :).filter (/=x))
```

I do not know if this is the correct process and If I could further "simplify" the lambda function, I think it is not posible because I actually would need the input to be 3 values. One being the list and two values need fot (:) and for (/=).

I would appreciate if someone could help so I can figure out the correct thinking process. I would like to fully understand it without moving to the next topic (Data Stuctures) so if there are any resources, keys to doing this I wil be very gratefull.

Comment: Looks like you've understood it pretty well so far. I don't really get what the question is here, though?

Comment: `liftA2 (.) (:) (filter . (/=))`, but this makes it probably less readable.'

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks a lot for the answer. I thought my thinking process was wrong so the question was which is the correct thinking process. Should I leave the question as answered or should I delete it?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I read in Hoogle the function definition and looks tricky but I will leave for when I am more used to Haskell. Thanks for the alternative.

Comment: @Metiwi `liftA2` can be a bit complicated to understand in full generality, but in the special case where its second and third arguments are functions, it's fairly simple: `liftA2 f g h x = f (g x) (h x)`.

Comment: You're doing great.  The `x` can be eliminated (in fact, lambdas can always be eliminated) but I wouldn't... going fully point-free can make things a bit of a mess, especially when you have to go back and read or change it later.

Comment: @DanielWagner I agree that it is easier to understand in the case you mentioned and if I fully understood it should be something like this:  `( ( (:) x).((filter.(/=)) x)  ) ys`.

I will still in the near future try to understand it's full generality. Thanks a lot for the simple explanation.

Comment: @luqui Thanks for the note, I will try to do as you say. I will find the balance between making it shorter and it's legibility. I think with time and better understanding of function composition and partial application I will find that balance.

Comment: There is some omnipresent euphoria among Haskell learners about highly compressed and obfuscated functions. But in real life, those are mostly undesired — the first thing you wrote is perfectly understandable and elegant. It has no redundancies either. The last one I couldn't immediately tell what it does. I also bet they compile to the same target code. Not saying that it's not cool (check out https://pointfree.io/, you're gonna love it), but I just don't see the point (hehe) here. To me you are asking us how to obfuscate your code more, thus I am voting to close due to lack of clarity.